# For each column in a data.frame find rows where column is the only one to have positive value

Tags: r, dataframe, unique

I need to know which elements of the row are unique for each column in data.frame and then print rownames in output.

My data example:

```
id  A   B   C
s1  1   2   1
s2  1   0   0
s3  0   12  3
s4  0   1   0
s5  0   1   0
```

I'd like to get simething like this:

```
$A s2
$B s4,s5
$C NA
```

Which means that:

A has only one unique element - s2

B has two unique elements - s4 and s5

and C has not any unique elements ,so it's filled by NA

I've tried

```
apply(data, 2, function(x) unique(x))
```

but it's not what I need..

Thanks a lot for suggestions!

Comment: @RonakShah Yes, my bad, there is should be S2, as you say, you are right.

Comment: The logic seems clear to me. If column A is the only one with positive value in row `s2` then return `s2` for that column. You can see that column `C` has no positive value where no other column has a postive value.

Comment: @snoram Yes, exactly.

Comment: So in a n times p data frame x, your definition of an value x[i, j] (with i = 1, ..., n and j = 1, ... , p) to be "unique" in column j is: all values x[i, -j] equal 0, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a rough base `R` solution:

```
helper <- function(x) {
  has_p <- x > 0
  if (sum(has_p) != 1) has_p[] <- FALSE 
  has_p
}
step1 <- as.data.frame(t(apply(df[-1], 1, helper)))

lapply(step1, function(x) df[[1]][x])

$A
[1] "s2"

$B
[1] "s4" "s5"

$C
character(0)
```

**Edit**

Here is a much simpler logic for the same solution:

```
rows <- rowSums(df[-1] > 0) == 1
lapply(df[-1], function(x) df[["id"]][rows & x > 0])
```

**Edit 2**

Put into one step (and add correct output `NA` when nothing unique):

```
lapply(
  as.data.frame(df[-1] > 0 & rowSums(df[-1] > 0) == 1),
  function(x) {
    if (all(!x)) return(NA)
    df[["id"]][x]
  }
)
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = c("s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5"), A = c(1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), B = c(2L, 0L, 12L, 1L, 1L), C = c(1L, 0L, 3L, 
0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @AndrewK. Cool, your problem is a bit unusual. I just added a simpler solution.

Comment: The second option should be the efficient one

Comment: @akrun because it doesn't have the extra `if (all(!x))`, right? or see anything else?

Comment: Yes and there are no additional steps to convert to data.frame